# Aws Rekognition - Search faces by image return maximum one match

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

Im using Aws Rekognition searchImageByFace function, for searching for the face id that matches between input image and a specific collection.
Everything works great except of the fact that the response I got includes maximum of one face match even if the input image as multiple faces.

I have tried to set the following:
MaxFaces: 6,
FaceMatchThreshold: 70

But it didn't help.

I would appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is working the way it was designed.

`SearchImagebyFace` only searches against the **largest** face in the input image, as per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_SearchFacesByImage.html):

> For a given input image, first detects the largest face in the image,
> and then searches the specified collection for matching faces.

`MaxFaces` in this case refers to the number of results, not the number of faces in the input image:

> Maximum number of faces to return. The operation returns the maximum
> number of faces with the highest confidence in the match.

To do what you want to do, you would need to first call `IndexFaces` to index all the faces in the input image, and then call `SearchFaces` on each face ID:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/search-face-with-id-procedure.html